# Wild violets gone -now what ? What is the right sequence of operations to re seed?

Tags: lawn, weed-control

My backyard was the largest plantation of wild violets known in North America. The grass was gone almost suffocated and in order to remove them I let them grow for the entire summer (so that they at least can kill the grass and make the removal easier
The Home Depot Billy the goat sod cutter did a very good job adjusted to the maximum depth. Removing the cuts was a nightmare because unlike the sod the wild violets do not keep the soil slices together so they break in small pieces when you try to remove them
You can guess how bad it is here
[image]
And here is after the massacre
[image]

Now I need to rent a bin and dispose that crap and get soil and seeds
What is the right order of operations here ?
I am thinking:
-use a rototiler to break the soil
-level the soil (the previous owner did a poor job when he spread the soil after he excavated to build the patio)
-not sure if I need to compact after this
-add seeds
-add top soil

Comment: You do need to make sure all the root material from each violet has been completely removed or there's a risk they will grow again through your new lawn. Is there a reason you're not laying sod instead of seeding?

Comment: The cost is the main reason.
Yes I guess rototiling the soil and then using a rake to remove any traces of roots will take care of that

Comment: the area that I would need sod for is 1400sqf

Comment: besides that I think the chances are better with seeds than with sod at this time of the year

Comment: I don't know where you are so can't comment on whether seed or sod is better at this time of year, but yes, that is a lot of sod to cover that amount of space. I was thinking more about the number of seeds the violets will have left in the soil which are likely to germinate along with your grass seed...

Comment: I will definitelly watch for them in the spring to kill them 
The sod cutter cut 1.5" deep and from my experience they do not go that deep, they have a strange growing pattern, they go half inch or one inch deep after that they go horizontal ...I manually tried to clean the area around a small three and it worked, they did not grow back but since they took over my entire lawn doing that was not feasable

Comment: I would not rototill because it destroys the tilth of your soil. In the US, we aerate instead, which leaves the soil in its native state but breaks up compaction. I have a ton of violets in my lawn and can tell you that you still have violets in your lawn, as Bamboo mentioned - they set and "shattered" their fall seed (zone 5) about two weeks ago. You will have to remove the seedlings by hand in the next year or two. You won't see them in the spring - only in late summer or, more likely, in 2022 :(

Comment: whenever they show up again I will kill them. 
They will be definitely fewer than they used to be (I had tons as you can see in that far top left corner of the picture